# finishing attic above garage

Tags: attic

I have a 2 car garage about 20 by 20 in size. Planning to build an attic storage/bonus room above it.The space above garage measures about 18 by 20 with minimum hight of 6 feet, and an access can be build from 2nd floor hallway/bedroom.
Should I worry if the foundation of the garage is strong enough for the attic, before reinforce the attic floor?

Thanks so much in advance for your answer.

Answer (score 3):

That would depend on how good the foundation is. Normally, the foundation is adequately overbuilt that it's not a concern. The weak link in this sort of conversion is USUALLY the "attic" floor above the garage wich is typically marginal even for light storage, and far from occupancy loads, over a very long span. Bringing that up to an adequate structure is a significant project if it was not built as such from the start.